# Strange behavior when updating an iframe with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

In the following code, when you click the link it swaps out the iframe src attribute with another video as expected. What I find strange is that it appears to create a history in my browser, allowing me to navigate backward and forward between the two videos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $("#link").attr('href');
        $("#video").attr('src', url);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/eef3bRjYTYg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<p><a id="link" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/0h6nInv4RY4">Click me</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

If I update the code, however, by wrapping the iframe in a div and replace the entire contents of that div (as opposed to just changing the src attribute), it swaps out the video with no browser history.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $("#link").attr('href');
        $("#video").html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + url + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="video">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/eef3bRjYTYg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<a id="link" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/0h6nInv4RY4">Click me</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this expected behavior or can anyone explain to me why it is happening?

Comment: When you change a `src`, the old-one is expected to be stored to history. If you just change the content of an element, it's not affecting history.

Comment: Of course this is expected behavior, since it is nothing much else than f.e. changing the iframe contents by clicking a link that has its target set to the iframe. When you are replacing the whole iframe element with a new one however, there is nothing left in which any kind of history navigation _could_ take place – the old iframe element is gone for good.